# Style one single column with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Maybe I want something impossible. 
I want a website with only a single column styled with flexbox. The purpose is that only one column stretches its height to the footer regardless the size of the content of the column. Something like below structure:

[image]

I try to reach that with this code (I am using bootstrap):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">  
     <header class="col-md-12">
       stuff...
     </header>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-a">
       stuff...
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 col-b">
       Stuff...
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-c">
        <div class="col-c-child">
          Stuff..
        </div>
     </div>
     <footer class="col-md-12">
       Stuff
     </footer>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then adding in the CSS this specific for the `col-c` and `col-c-child`:

```
.col-c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-c-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

But is not working. 
Any idea?

**THE SOLUTION**:

- Create a row for the `header`, other for the content and other for the `footer`, that is - don't have everything in the same row.
- Build a div-wrapper englobing col-a, col-b and col-c with `display:flex` and `flex-direction: row;`
- get rid of col-c-child
- col-c with `flex: 1;`

Thanks to @jelleB who elucidated me for part of it.

Comment: You can't do that without involving the parent of the column-column child with flexbox too. You need some method of calculating the height of the colc-c div.

Comment: Thank you. Thankfully a solution was found and now I really understand what you mean. It makes all sense what you are saying. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Put the header and the footer in different rows.
- You should build a div below col-a (without content)
- Use min-height: 100% on the row    where you put col-a/col-b/col-c in

Give this a shot

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it out! And then I give you feedback.

Comment: Thank you! It really contributed for half of the solution. the other half was to change the `flex-direction: column`; to `flex-direction: row;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to wrap your middle divs, you can do the following:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container #body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 100px; /*change to whatever width you want*/
}

.center {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/*styles for demo*/
header,
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: green;
}

.center {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem lies in the `height:100%`

If I am not mistaken, you cannot do that unless the parent container has its height defined. If the parent container's height is also defined as a percentage then the parent's parent container's height must also be defined. This hierarchy continues up to the body tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My mistake. I should have mention that I have the body and html with height: 100%.